# Is there any way to dynamically assign header to con-cat the XML ELEMENTS in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I'm trying to build a common interface that converts 24 different XML Structures to Flate Files by concating XML elements. In Dell Boomi, we have an option to dynamically pass variable names to XSLT. As shown below:

`<xsl:variable name="headers" select="boomi:get-ddp('DDP_Headers')"/>`

We have stored all the 24 XML node names in the table rows. Ex:

`CLIENTID,',',CLIENTNAME,',',CLIENTADDRESS,',',....,',',CLIENTCONTACT`

`PERSONID,',',PERSONNAME,',',PERSONADDRESS,',',....,',',PERSONCONTACT`

`......,',',.......,',',... etc`

When we are passing the variable name and using that in Concat function it is taking as a string and printing only the String instead of XML Element values. Here is the code which we tried.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:boomi="http://boomi.com/custom-function">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
  <xsl:variable name="headers" select="boomi:get-ddp('DDP_Headers')"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//externalKPIClientProductivity">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($headers,'&#xA;')" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The code is working fine with the below example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:boomi="http://boomi.com/custom-function">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />

  <xsl:variable name="headers" select="boomi:get-ddp('DDP_Headers')"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//externalKPIClientProductivity">
            <!-- <xsl:value-of select="@id" />  -->
    <!--<xsl:value-of
                select="concat($headers,'&#xA;')" />-->
                <xsl:value-of
                select="concat(CLIENTID,',',CLIENTNAME,',',CLIENTADDRESS,',',PAY,',',CLIENTLOCATION,',',XRFCODE,',',CLIENTCONTACT,'&#xA;')" /> 
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can someone please help me out how to pass these dynamic XML Elements to Concat function so that it will work as XML Elements and retrieve the data instead of printing the same String file as example:

```
CLIENTID,',',CLIENTNAME,',',CLIENTADDRESS,',',PAY,',',CLIENTLOCATION,',',XRFCODE,',',CLIENTCONTACT
CLIENTID,',',CLIENTNAME,',',CLIENTADDRESS,',',PAY,',',CLIENTLOCATION,',',XRFCODE,',',CLIENTCONTACT
CLIENTID,',',CLIENTNAME,',',CLIENTADDRESS,',',PAY,',',CLIENTLOCATION,',',XRFCODE,',',CLIENTCONTACT
..................
```

Thanks in advance!!
DC

Comment: First decide which XSLT version you use or want to use, it hardly makes sense to use the tags for all three existing versions at the same time. I would also add a tag for the tool/environment ("boomi") you use XSLT with.

Comment: Can you change the DDP_Headers to just a comma delimited list of element names without the comma delimiter?

Comment: Also, do you know how to do this non dynamically?  In 1.0 that's how you'll need to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your environment supports XSLT 3 with Saxon PE or EE (https://help.boomi.com/bundle/integration/page/int-XSLT_Stylesheet_Components_13300ba8-5e94-4b14-b6bd-5b90d7002233.html seems to suggest that) or uses Saxon 10 where `xsl:evaluate` is supported in all editions then one way would be to use e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="fields" as="xs:string">foo,bar,baz</xsl:param>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//item">
            <xsl:value-of separator=",">
                <xsl:evaluate xpath="$fields" context-item="."/>
            </xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that I have solely passed in the field names in the param and have chosen to delegate the separator introduction to `xsl:value-of`. You could however also use a string with any separator string inserted like in your question and pass it to `xsl:evaluate`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="#all" version="3.0">

    <xsl:param name="fields" as="xs:string">foo,',',bar,',',baz</xsl:param>

    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//item">
            <xsl:evaluate xpath="$fields" context-item="."/>
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As a third option in XSLT 3 you could try a static parameter with a shadow attribute:

```
<xsl:variable name="headers" static="yes" select="boomi:get-ddp('DDP_Headers')"/>

<xsl:value-of _select="concat({$headers},'&#xA;')" />
```

I can't tell, however, whether your extension function in your environment is set up to be used with static parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Martin!! This really helped me. Like you've mentioned `<xsl:for-each select="//item">` When I'm passing `<xsl:for-each select="$node">` It is showing error as the node is an atomic value, could you please help me like how to even pass the for-each element also dynamically. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @DhanushChikoti, try `_select="{$node}"` (make sure to declare the parameter or variable `node` with `static="yes"`) or ask a new question with minimal but complete samples and a description.